# Computer does not boot from dvd

Tags: windows-8

I accidentally formatted partition containing windows 8. Now the hard disk is not detected by bios and a  message is shown " Operating System missing". The system does not boot from windows bootable DVD. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To get into BIOS to change the boot order you'll need to press some keys when the computer starts... it's different by manufacturer but often DEL or F10, or F2, could be F1, F2, F3, ... up to F12. There should be a brief message saying what to press (if you haven't set a fast boot or timeout or splash screen).

Changing the boot order in BIOS is permanent (until you change it back).

There is often another button to press at boot time to get to a "Boot Menu," to select a different disk to boot from this time only.

Seraching for your computer model should give results on what keys to press, how to get into BIOS and change the boot order.

---

Or if your HD really isn't detected at all by the BIOS (it doesn't show up when booting a live linux like Ubuntu/Mint) then it could have failed or been unplugged. Even if it were formatted or erased it would still show up in BIOS, and able to be reformatted, if it were still working.

Answer (score 0):

depend on your motherboard model. usually the HD is the primary boot, but you can change the primary boot to DVD, some motherboard models allow boot from second boot source if the primary one is failed. that's mean if you find in your BIOS that the DVD is primary or secondary boot, most probably your DVD does not burned to be bootable.